# How to perform ETL from RDBMS to Neo4j

Tags: mysql, rdbms, etl, neo4j, pentaho

I have a mature 50+ tables web application based on mySQL. In order to do some advanced data mining I want to use Neo4j and the goodnes of cypher. However I'm having a hard time migrating my data from RDBMS to Neo4j. I don't wan't to do it by hand, because this is generally unmaintainable.

I use pentaho which supports the Neo4j JDBC, however I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around loading the extracted data to Neo4j since the GUI is clearly designed for RDBMS and there are no sources about how to do it. Had anyone run into a similar problem and found a solution?

Comment: Have you read the guides? http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Getting+Started  Also check out the blogs diethardsteiner.blogspot.com and also Slawo: http://type-exit.org/adventures-with-open-source-bi/

Comment: @Codek I did and they either don't apply or I'm not getting something. It would be much easier to get something from Neo4j and put it to RDBMS but I can't find an easy way to do it the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

JDBC Driver that Neo4J provides are for Cypher queries ( which are select only). There are no inserts , updates or delete. You will have to adopt some other means like .. exporting rdbms stuff to csv and importing csv to Neo4J.

Answer (score 1):

maybe it's too late but I faced to this problem and I could solve it.
At first you need to add `Table Input` tool for getting records from MySQL then you can add `execute SQL script` from `Scripting` tool.
create your `transformation` from `Table input` to `Execute SQL Script`. 
then `Get fields` and check mark :

- Execute for each row?
- Execute as a single Statement

then you can add your Cypher Query Like that:

```
CREATE(NodeName:NodeLabel{field1:?,field2:?,field3:?,...})
```

Comment: @user78028 Thanks for sharing the information. If I am not mistaken, you were able to update Neo4J with the changed data set from MySQL using Pentaho Kettle, right?